# How to develop Native application in visual studio for tizen platform

Tags: visual-studio, tizen, tizen-native-app

I try to develop the native application in visual studio using this reference link [this is reference link](https://docs.tizen.org/application/vstools/Tizen/native/).

I follow same step which is in the link. when I try to build the project I am getting this below errors.
[image]

and the output log is

```
Build started...
1>FastUpToDateForTizen:  'C:\Users\hello\source\repos\TizenNative1\TizenNative1\tizen-manifest.xml' was not found. skip to check ... (TizenNative1)
1>------ Build started: Project: TizenNative1, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>Tizen Native project Build starts here ------------
1>C:\Users\hello\source\repos\TizenNative1\TizenNative1
1>Workspace: 'C:\Users\hello\source\repos\TizenNative1'
1>Using default certificates
1>Done. Made 11 targets from 18 files in 9ms
1>ninja: Entering directory `debug\wearable-6.0\x86'
1>[1/4] CC obj/TizenNative1/src/tizennative1.o
1>[2/4] SOLINK tpk/lib/libtizennative1.so
1>[3/4] STAMP obj/TizenNative1/all.stamp
1>[4/4] STAMP obj/build/build.stamp
1>ninja: Entering directory `debug\wearable-6.0\x86'
1>ninja: no work to do.
1>tz : error : cannot pack because no executable found
1>C:\Users\hello\source\repos\TizenNative1\TizenNative1\TizenNative1.targets(42,9): error MSB3073: The command "C:\tizen-studio\tools\tizen-core\tz.exe pack C:\Users\hello\source\repos\TizenNative1" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "TizenNative1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========
```

can anyone please help me. what is the issue ? how can i solve this issue ? please anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

For me,
I have no issue.
I think that you built a wearable 6.0 native app and arm arch on VS2022.

Could you update Tizen SDK as the latest version?
Till March 16th, the latest version is 4.5.1
Thanks

1>Package File Location: E:\test345\TizenNative1\debug\wearable-6.0\x86\org.example.tizennative1-0.0.1-x86.tpk
1>[6/6] STAMP obj/build/pack.stamp
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========